# How to show the original price in the shopping cart in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I'm having problems trying to show the original unit price in the shopping cart in Magento. By default Magento only shows the special price but I would like to also show the original price to highlight the savings.

I know which template needs changing which is /template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml.

On line 145 it shows

```
<?php 
 echo $this->helper('checkout')->
               formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition())
?>
```

which displays the special price. I just don't know the syntax to display the original price.

Answer (score 5):

see below for an alternative method, 
i'm not sure if $_item->getPrice has access to the non special price, so jumped it over to product

```
            <?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getPrice(); ?>
```

within

```
             <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
             <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        // insert it here
             <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite sure which template you suggest editing but your reply did help me come up with the following solution which work well:

Comment: <?php if ($_item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice()): ?>
 <span class="rrp-price"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()->getPrice()); ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>